# Rails date_select helper not showing two digit month numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

According to [this](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) Rails should be displaying two digit month numbers, e.g. `07` for July but in my Rails 4.2 app it doesn't. July is shown as "7" as are all the other one digit months. On the days it works, however. Is this a bug?

```
f.date_select :date, :order => [ :day, :month, :year ], :use_month_numbers => true, :use_two_digit_numbers => true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this and found that it is working with this code.

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :order => [ :day, :month, :year ], :use_two_digit_numbers => true %>
```

I tried just by removing :user_month_number, and it display months in two digit.
Hope it help!

Comment: You are right! It works! You just have to omit `:use_month_numbers => true`. Feels almost like a bug to me...